# How do I get notified when the Dropbox app is updated?

Tags: macos, dropbox

I realized that I was running a very old version of **Dropbox** for Mac. Somehow I was not notified about the latest updates. I was expecting the same behavior as apps like **1Password**.

In the past, I missed out ***Selective Sync*** by few months which I was eagerly waiting for.

I was running *1.1.35* (Under **Preferences**/ **Account**) and the latest version is *1.1.43* .

Where can I find the config to let **Dropbox** auto-update/prompt me on every release, similar to **1Password**.

Comment: Dropbox probably isn't in the Mac App Store because it needs to do lower-level things that are outside the guidelines for apps in the Store. Can't say for sure, but given how it hooks into the filesystem, it seems likely.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [MacDropUpdate](http://wiki.dropbox.com/DropboxAddons/MacDropUpdate).

It's an automatic updater that automatically updates your Dropbox to the latest forum build of Dropbox. Works on OS X Leopard|Snow Leopard|Lion.

Edit: it's also Growl-enabled, so you may get notified whenever Dropbox's been updated.

Answer (score 2):

Inspired by this question, I made an RSS feed for Mac betas. You can find it at http://feeds.feedburner.com/dropboxmacbeta

The official RSS feed https://www.dropbox.com/release_notes/rss.xml has the release notes, the feedburner feed links directly to the DMG so you can download it, and it links to the forum discussion for that specific build so you can see if there are any details/issues that other people have found.

(More info available at http://tj.luo.ma/post/9957496270/dropbox-rss if you want it.)

Answer (score 1):

Normally Dropbox pushes updates out in the background without you detect it - but not all updates will be pushed - it appears that it is only critical ones (or major releases).

The latest Lion compatible release is however 1.2.28 (which is still a beta) - http://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=43550&replies=16

Comment: Is there a way I get notified like other apps even for Beta versions w/o following Dropbox's blog ?

Comment: Not to my knowledge - some of the beta updates was pushed after the first install of a beta release - but how Dropbox decide when to push an update and when not to - I don't know. And I don't think they will offer an automatically update like e.g. 1Password you mentions. BUT you can subscribe to Dropbox's RSS feed: https://www.dropbox.com/release_notes/rss.xml - then you'll get the news.

Answer (score 0):

"[Bodega](http://appbodega.com/) makes the process painless by automatically checking the apps on your hard drive, and then ensuring you have the latest versions installed on your Mac. If you have an app that’s out of date and in the Bodega catalog, Bodega conveniently downloads and even installs the update for you."